# Make the application not visible in Google play store search for Marshmallow users

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to know that is it possible that marshmallow users do not see my application in google play store? I just published an application in google play store but it has some bugs when user of marshmallow version downloads it so basically i want to make that application invisible for marshmallow users so that until all the bugs are removed the app will be invisible for marshmallow user. Is it possible? please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `targetSdkVersion 21` in your `build.gradle` file. Currently it must be **23**

Comment: Yes it is 23 right now, making it 21 will make it not available for marshamallow user even if user search the app by name?

Comment: Yes it won't be available for marshmallow users even if anyone searches app by name as it would be targeted max for lollipop only..

Comment: Thankyou Let me apply this and get back to you

Comment: Its Done, Thankyou :)

Comment: but after doing that you cannot upload your application on playstore.

Comment: @ArslanAli Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to list the application for API levels 23 and above, give the `maxSdkVersion` as 22 in `build.gradle`. `targetSdkVersion`is an integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. If you want more clarification please refer : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html